# Send message into SQS from LAmbda with AWS-SDK-CPP

Tags: c++, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I want to send message to AWS SQS from AWS Lambda with a c++ application using the aws-sdk-cpp 1.8.154.

The related code:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration clientConfig("default");
Aws::SQS::SQSClient sqs(clientConfig);
Aws::SQS::Model::SendMessageOutcome ret = sqs.SendMessage(sqsRequest);
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Send result with: " << ret.GetError().GetMessage();
```

and I get the following output:

curlCode: 77, Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

If I disable SSL verification, everything works fine.

I have tried to set

```
clientConfig.caPath = "/etc/ssl/certs/";
```

or

```
clientConfig.caFile = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt";
```

without success.

The lambda execution role has AmazonSQSFullAccess, but it doesn't help.

Can anybody help me how to get things work?

The only strong related issue that I found: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp/issues/95 but the questioner didn't provided the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is on page: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp

Setting the CA correctly:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration config;
config.caFile = "/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt";
```